# Robot Framework- TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Tags: python, selenium, automation, robotframework

I am new to robot framework(using ride) and I have created a project in which I have used user keywords to generate random value i.e.

```
*** Keywords ***
Random Value
    [Arguments]    ${x_boundry}    ${y_boundry}
    Evaluate    random.randint(${x_boundry},${y_boundry})    random
```

Now I have stored random value in a scalar variable i.e.

```
${ran}    Random Value    1    5
```

And used it in any Input field (which has no restriction on entering numeric value) i.e.

```
Input Text    //input[@id='firstname']    ${ran}
```

But after running a program error occurs-

```
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len().
```

Using this in ride robot framework. Please let me know if any other information required.

Comment: `Input Text    //input[@id='firstname']    ${ran}` - what is it supposed to do?

Comment: @Psytho- In automation it is used to enter some text in field. For example- in email  field you have to enter an email address then, this keyword is used.

Comment: Is the format of the locator (`//input[@id='firstname']`) correct?

Comment: Yes absolutely correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't return anything from `Random Value`. That is why `${ran}` remains `None`. You have to return a value from `Random Value`:

```
Random Value
    [Arguments]    ${x_boundry}    ${y_boundry}
    ${output}    Evaluate    random.randint(${x_boundry},${y_boundry})    random
    [Return]    ${output}
```